# Why does this GROUP BY cause a full table scan?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table of `projects` and a table of `tasks`, with each task referencing a single project. I want to get a list of projects sorted by their due dates along with the number of tasks in each project. I can pretty easily write this query two ways. First, using `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.name, p.due_date, COUNT(t.id) as num_tasks
FROM projects p
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks t ON t.project_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.due_date ASC LIMIT 20;
```

Second, using a subquery:

```
SELECT p.name, p.due_date, (SELECT
   COUNT(*) FROM tasks t WHERE t.project_id = p.id) as num_tasks
FROM projects p
ORDER BY p.due_date ASC LIMIT 20;
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 10, and I've got indices on `projects.id`, `projects.due_date` and `tasks.project_id`. Why does the first query using the `GROUP BY` clause do a full table scan while the second query makes proper use of the indices? It seems like these should compile down to the same thing.

Note that if I remove the `GROUP BY` and the `COUNT(t.id)` from the first query it will run quickly, just with lots of duplicate rows. So the problem is with the `GROUP BY` clause, not the `JOIN`. This seems like it's about the simplest `GROUP BY` one could do, so I'd like to understand if/how to make it more efficient before moving on to more complicated queries.

*Edit* — here's the result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. First query:

```
Limit  (cost=41919.58..41919.63 rows=20 width=53) (actual time=1046.762..1046.771 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=41919.58..42169.58 rows=100000 width=53) (actual time=1046.760..1046.765 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: p.due_date
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.71..39258.62 rows=100000 width=53) (actual time=0.109..1002.890 rows=100000 loops=1)
              Group Key: p.id
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.71..35758.62 rows=500000 width=49) (actual time=0.072..807.603 rows=500702 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (p.id = t.project_id)
                    ->  Index Scan using projects_pkey on projects p  (cost=0.29..3542.29 rows=100000 width=45) (actual time=0.025..38.363 rows=100000 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using project_id_idx on tasks t  (cost=0.42..25716.33 rows=500000 width=8) (actual time=0.038..531.097 rows=500000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.573 ms
Execution Time: 1046.934 ms
```

Second query:

```
Limit  (cost=0.29..92.61 rows=20 width=49) (actual time=0.079..0.443 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using project_date_idx on projects p  (cost=0.29..461594.09 rows=100000 width=49) (actual time=0.076..0.432 rows=20 loops=1)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=4.54..4.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=20)
                ->  Index Only Scan using project_id_idx on tasks t  (cost=0.42..4.53 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=5 loops=20)
                      Index Cond: (project_id = p.id)
                      Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.284 ms
Execution Time: 0.551 ms
```

And if anyone wants to try to exactly reproduce this, here's my setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE projects (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    due_date timestamp NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tasks (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    project_id integer NOT NULL,
    data real NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO projects (name, due_date) SELECT
    md5(random()::text),
    timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00' +
       random() * (timestamp '2030-01-01 20:00:00' - timestamp '2020-01-01 10:00:00')
    FROM generate_series(1, 100000);

INSERT INTO tasks (project_id, data)
    SELECT CAST(1 + random()*99999 AS integer), random()
    FROM generate_series(1, 500000);

CREATE INDEX project_date_idx ON projects ("due_date");
CREATE INDEX project_id_idx ON tasks ("project_id");
ALTER TABLE tasks ADD CONSTRAINT task_foreignkey FOREIGN KEY ("project_id") REFERENCES "projects" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Comment: What happens if you use `COUNT(p.id)` instead of `COUNT(t.id)`?

Comment: Please post EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: These queries are not equivalent. `COUNT(t.id)` in the first one counts the number of tasks per project that have non-null task id-s which strictly speaking is not the same as the number of tasks. Try `COUNT(t.project_id)` and see what happens.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm you're right that they're not _exactly_ equivalent, but practically they're the same because there are no non-null task ids. Using `COUNT(t.project_id)` is more apples-to-apples, but it yields the same poor performance.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Using `COUNT(p.id)` doesn't improve the performance any. And the non-toy query that I have in mind uses a different aggregation function, so I really do need to be able to access the data in the `tasks` table.

Comment: "I'd like to understand if/how to make it more efficient before moving on to more complicated queries.", this sounds like premature optimisation. Your complicated query might behave very different from the random data you present over here.

Comment: @FrankHeikens The point isn't that I want to optimize this query in particular. I already have optimized it by using the select subquery. Instead, the point is that I don't understand *why* one query is so much better than the other, and I'd like to understand why in order to better understand how PostgreSQL works.